# How to implement Dependency Injections in Utility class in RazorPages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

**I have the following in startup**

```
services.AddTransient<IInjections, Injections>();
```

**I have the following class "Injections"**

```
Contexts.ConsiliIntContext _consiliContext { get; set; }

public Injections(Contexts.ConsiliIntContext ConsiliContext) {
            _consiliContext = ConsiliContext;
}

public ConsiliIntContext GetConsiliContext() {
            return _consiliContext;
}
```

**In my razorpage I can do this to get access to the dbcontext, works fine**

```
@inject Helpers.IInjections Injections
```

**But how do I inject it into my utils class, I have tried to implement it as an interface but I do not know what I should return in the implemented methods**

```
public class Utils : IInjections{}




public ConsiliIntContext GetConsiliContext()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
```

I know there are a lot of documentation on DI, and I have read and read but found no good samples.

I am using ASP .Net Core 3.1

Thanks
Thomas

Answer (score 0):

Don't inject a utility class, just inject the db context into the class it's being used by:

```
public class Demo
{
   public Demo(ConsiliIntContext context)
   { 

   }
}
```

Comment: I do no inject a utility class, what do you mean? for the record the context is just an example , I have 5 contexts I need to enable in my utitly class

Comment: I meant don't inject those contexts into a utility class, and then inject that utility class into the class where it will be used.  Just inject the context (or other interfaces) directly into the class.   Otherwise you will be losing one of the useful capabilities of DI, which is scoping (creating new instances per message, for example).